# '(' expected near 'myFunction'

Tags: lua, lua-table

Getting error in title whilst trying to make a table in Lua, as such:

```
MyTable = {}
table.insert(MyTable, function MyFunction() end)
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks,
MakePrint0

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
The `table.insert()` adds index keys as numbers in a sequence.
You have to choose the anonymous syntax form for your function to put it in as a index key that is a number...

```
table.insert(MyTable, function() end)
```

Now it is the last index key so you can call...

```
MyTable[#MyTable]()
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for the solution. By the way, just wondering, you can't make the function local, and then call it outside of that table code-block, right (it would need to be global)?

Answer (score 0):

`function MyFunction() end` is equivalent to `MyFunction = function () end`

`function MyFunction () end` is a statement. It defines a function value and stores it in the global variable `MyFunction`. It does not return a value. `function () end` is an expression. It returns a function value. This is also called an anonymous function.

`table.insert(MyTable, function MyFunction() end)` yields an error as you provide a statement where a value is expected.

`table.insert(MyTable, function () end)` on the other hand inserts a newly created function value into the table.

> just wondering, you can't make the function local, and then call it
> outside of that table code-block, right (it would need to be global)?

No you can use a local function.

```
local MyTable = {} 
local function MyFunction () end
table.insert(MyTable, MyFunction)
```

Now you can call `MyFunction` or `MyTable[1]`.

usually you would do something like this:

```
MyTable = {}
function MyTable.HelloWorld ()
  print("hello world")
end

MyTable.HelloWorld()
```

is more intuitive than

```
MyTable = {}
table.insert(MyTable, function () print("hello world") end)
MyTable[1]()
```

But in some cases using numeric indices makes sense. Not sure what you want to achive.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I'm confused on what you mean in the bottom two lines, though. Are you saying that you can declare functions within tables in that way, rather than using the table.insert function? In this way, they also don't have to be anonymous? I tried doing so, but MyFunction() wasn't recognized, and returned a nil value in the console.

Comment: I only suggested that you might use names instead of numeric indices for your table. in case you didn't know that is possible. still nto sure what you want to achieve. see edited answer

Comment: Oh, I see. So declaring the function as tableName.functionName inserts it into the table? How could you confirm this/find all the elements that are in a table (since trying to identify a function as a numerical index won't work)?

Comment: `function MyTable.MyFunction () end` is equivalent to `MyTable["MyFunction"] = function () end`  you assign a function value to a table field with a name instead of a number as key.  I don't understand your last sentences. what do you want to confirm? why should a numerical index not work? you identify the function through the name you gave to it.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to Lua, sorry if my questions are a bit jarring to understand. I'm basically asking why: 

If

`local myTable = {} 
local function myFunction() print("Hello World!") end table.insert(myTable, myFunction)
myTable[1]()`

works when trying to call the function through [1], why doesn't it work the same with:

`local newTable = {}
local function newTable.newFunction() print("Hello World!") end
newTable[1]()`?

Shouldn't putting newTable.newFunction() insert newFunction into newTable? So then I can just call it through the numeric index of [1]?

Comment: why should you be able to access the function through myTable[1] if you assigned it to myTable["newFunction"]?  find out how indexing works and what syntactic sugars exist in Lua.  this is very important!   myTable.newFunction is the same as myTable["newFunction"]    myTable[1] is still nil. only if you explicitly assign something to that key or if you do it using table.insert it will work